# How can I animate elements that move due to other nearby elements having $.fadeIn() called on them?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

Imagine a horizontal `ul` of items like this:

`Item 1 | Item 2 | Item 4`

I wish to insert `Item 3` into its appropriate position. If I assume that it is already there, but simply has `display: none;`, I can call `$('.item3').fadeIn()` to make it fade in using jQuery.

Unfortunately, doing so makes `Item 4` snap to the left/right before `Item 3` fades in. Is there a way to cause `Item 4` to smoothly animate to make space for the new item?

I have tried using jQuery's `show('slide')` for this, but it does not seem to play nicely with horizontal `ul`. I'm also curious about this in general; is there some way to apply the `transition` property to make any movement of an element smooth?

Minimum Working Example http://jsfiddle.net/L2uh36rc/

Note that when `Item 3` fades in and out, `Item 4` snaps left or right to accomodate that change. I'd like it to smoothly animate left or right, instead.

Comment: Can you provide a [minimal, working example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? Otherwise this will be hard to answer.

Comment: Sure; I have updated the question with a JSfiddle link.

Comment: I see the snapping of Item 4, but Item 1 and Item 2 seem OK to me.

Comment: Apologies; my original question assumed that the list was right-justified but I didn't think it was appropriate for the minimal example. I will update the question to just refer to Item 4; in this example I'm trying to make it smoothly animate and not snap.

Comment: If the elements have fixed width then it's not difficult ([example](http://jsfiddle.net/pxe13rmx/)). If they have 100% width it's a bit more complicated but still doable. For inline block elements with variable auto width however, you will need to resort to black magic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution possible :

```js
$(
    function() {
        $('#toggle').on('click', function() {
            var target = $('.target');
            var w = target.data('originalWidth');
            var curWidth = target.width();
            
            if( target.css('display') === 'none'){
                if( ! w ) {
                    w = curWidth;
                    target.data('originalWidth' , w);
                }
                target.css({width:0,opacity : 0}).show().animate( 
                    { opacity : 1 , width : w + 'px'} , 
                    777 , 
                    function(){ 
                        $('.target').show(0);
                    }
                );
            }else{
                target.animate( 
                    { opacity : 0 , width : 0 + 'px'} , 
                    777 , 
                    function(){ 
                        $('.target').hide(0);
                    }
                );
            };
            
            
        });
 }
);
```

```css
ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    overflow : hidden;
    white-space : nowrap;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li class="target" style="display: none;">Item 3</li>
    <li>Item 4</li>
</ul>

<button id="toggle">Toggle Item</button>
<div></div>
```

Comment: Thank you! Sorry it took me forever to accept your answer :P